# Redirecting does not work correctly every time in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I will try to explain my idea. (.net framework 4.0)
Every time when I go in error to handle it in OnException method.

```
 protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //here we have to handle the error !!!
        string controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        string actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var dataError = $"User:{CurrentUserId} Department:{CurrentUserDitId} ErrorMessage:{filterContext.Exception.Message} ActionName:{actionName} ControllerName:{controllerName}";
        LogServices2.LogSaveError(dataError);
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url.Action("LogOn", "User").Replace("/ExchangeMessages", ""),true);            
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
```

Ok I implementate error in controller (throw new exception("..."))
and handle it in OnException to save log and redirect to login page.
Ok but I delete it throw new ex... and every time continue to go in login page when I click the same link in menu.WHY?

My code for redirect is:(is not changed before implementaation in OnException)

```
public ActionResult RedirectProject(string endpoint, string controllerName = null)
    {
        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        bool isPersistent = false;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
          1,                                     // ticket version
          username,                              // authenticated username
          DateTime.Now,                          // issueDate
          DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),           // expiryDate
          isPersistent,                          // true to persist across browser sessions
          string.Join("|", ((RolePrincipal)User).GetRoles()),// can be used to store additional user data
          FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);  // the path for the cookie

        // Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
        // Add the cookie to the request to save it           
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
            FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket))
        { HttpOnly = true });
        // Your redirect logic
        Response.Redirect(_helper.RedirectFull(Request, endpoint, controllerName ?? "SEOS"),false);
        Response.End();
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

All other links from menu works?
If I change the name of the action works again.

Comment: In general, you should not be directly manipulating responses with in ASP.NET MVC. That breaks the whole controller action method paradigm. If you want to perform a redirect, have your action method return a RedirectResult.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Clear the cache in browser.
If set to **TRUE** in:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url.Action("LogOn", "User").Replace("/ExchangeMessages", ""),**true**);
```

…then save in the browser's cache to redirect you permanently based on the URL.